# How to include javascript with HTML in google sites?

Tags: javascript, html, google-sites

html and javascript work properly there as you can see.
but when I add this to a htmlbox in google sites, it shows an error saying "1+1: URI unknown:///unknown is malformed"

Help me,
thanks

Here's my html and javascript

```
[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/TvHdU/4/
```

Comment: heres code: http://jsfiddle.net/TvHdU/4/

Comment: This question is now the first response in google when searching for the error message; but the answer I found isn't here.  In my case the problem was a form tag with no "action" param.  I added action="#" and then validation passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Make sure when you hit page create that "webpage" was chosen in the dropdown.
- When the box comes up to edit the page, make sure that you click the <kbd>html</kbd> icon in the edit box.
- Copy the html you provided, and pasted it into the page and below it wrote script tags to contain the javascript you provided.

  ```
  <script>
  //your js code here
  </script>
  ```

Since Google restricts their sites, you have to use Google APIs to obtain the js code you need in order to make the Google Gadget work. [Here's the API site](https://developers.google.com/gadgets/docs/reference/)

This should give you what you need in order to get you Google Gadget working with JavaScript.

You can view the working google site I just created [here](https://sites.google.com/site/stackoverflowschennighan/), then click on "include html" link on left bar under "Home".

Comment: still i can't see fields after Street Address.

Comment: I figured it out, so it's because the google gadget is a fixed height. What you do is you edit the html of your page again, scroll ALL the way to the top into the google mumbo jumbo, and then scroll down until you see this: data-type="ggs-gadget" data-props="align:left;height:300; --- what you need to do is change that height to like 1000, or however much you need. Hope this helps! Here's the link to mine if you want to see: https://sites.google.com/site/stackoverflowschennighan/home/include-html

Comment: But the javascripts still not working. because it doesn't return an error alert when click'Submit' without any input

Comment: Yes you're correct, you'll have to actually make a gadget because google restricts a lot of things on their sites. Here's a guide on how: https://developers.google.com/gadgets/docs/basic  and here's a guide on the javascript functions you're allowed to use: https://developers.google.com/gadgets/docs/reference/  ---hopefully this helps. Google sites are different.

Comment: thanks.  i think google sites do not support alerts. so i used document.write and it worked.